# Save JSON with special characters (currency symbols)

Tags: json, scrapy, special-characters, unicode-escapes

I'm using Scrapy to extract some values from a website. One of the fields is "price" and I have something like:

```
...

item = {
        "title": title, 
        "url" : url, 
        "price":  {
                    "symbol": the_currency_symbol,
                    "amount": float_number
                   }
        }

yield item
```

I set the output to be a JSON file and I yield a dictionary item.

The problem is that when I open the output JSON with the items I see this:

```
{
    "title": title, 
    "url" : url, 
    "price": {
        "symbol": "\u00a3",
        "amount": 12.99
         }
}
```

How can I see the correct currency symbol in the JSON file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrapy json response convert in utf-8 encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41458394/scrapy-json-response-convert-in-utf-8-encode)

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy normally produces JSON feeds in ASCII encoding. Your JSON file has correct data but to see the currency symbol properly you can convert the output JSON file to UTF-8 encoding.

You can make Scrapy generate JSON in UTF-8 encoding by setting `FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING="utf-8"`. For more help, see the answers to the question: [Scrapy json response convert in utf-8 encode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41458394/1921546) and Scrapy documentation https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std-setting-FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING.

If you do not want to run the scraper again then you can use some tool like https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ on your JSON file like `jq file.json > outfile.json`. Then outfile.json will have proper symbols.